# Access: Generate manual sequence number

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form to generate contract number whenever the user submit what they fill in that form.
This is the example number:

> 00001/ABC/DEF/01/2013

the squence number is shown by '00001'. It means the next user who submit it in the same year will get the next number which '00002'.
to handle this I use this code in my submit button:

```
Dim strSQL As String, cNumber As Integer
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Contract_No FROM T_Report WHERE Year=2013 ORDER BY Contract_No DESC "
Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    cNumber = Left(rs!Contract_No, 5) + 1
Else
    cNumber = 1
End If
```

It works fine when the user submit it in different time. The problem arise when 2 or more users generate it in the same time. For example userA and userB click the button together, they will get '00001' and '00001'. What I want is another user get '00002', '00003', and so on. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You should store the sequence number in a separate field of type `Autonumber`

Comment: In the SQL, use `Max` rather than top i.e. `SELECT Max(Contact_No) FROM T_Report`

Comment: Are you doing this before the user enters other info on the contract?  If so, this will be common, since you are pulling the number for multiple users well before they try to save.  You could put this code in right before they save, or save it right away before they make other changes.  But AutoNumber would be a safer bet.

Comment: I am also assuming that the year will not be hard-coded, so when January rolls around you won't have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is store "meaning" in your Contract Number field. This is generally considered to be a bad idea. Your best bet is to just use an Autonumber field as your Primary Key field. If you insist on using the above scheme, you have basically two options (that I can think of).

Your first and best option is to assign your contract numbers on the Form's BeforeUpdate event. This way they will get assigned when the record actually gets saved/committed.

Your second option is to run DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord right after you generate your Contract Number. This usually doesn't work very well because you may have fields or controls that don't pass the validation rules you've put in place.